# How to open previous tab in Safari app in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, safari, mobile-safari

I'm currently trying to open a web `URL` in Safari iOS app from my app.

Here is the **scenario**,

1. User clicks on a *Button-1* that launches Safari app and opens *URL-1* in *Tab-1* let's say.
2. User navigates through the webpage and other links inside it in Safari and then closes the app and Safari after some time.
3. User opens the app again and clicks on *Button-1* again.

**Problem statement** - *Button-1* should launch Safari with the same *Tab-1* that was opened earlier.

How can I achieve the above behaviour?

Comment: Save url-1 (as Strong)  in UserDefault

Comment: @PtitXav How will this help in opening the same tab every time in Safari?

Comment: UserDefault are saved between 2 activations of the app. So at the relaunch of app you get url-1 from UserDefault and so you can do 1 again.

Comment: @PtitXav I don't think you understood the question. Its just that I want to reopen a previous tab in Safari based on my url.